# User control doesn't react when I pressed a tab button

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows application: a main form and several user controls on it.

Tab button doesn't work as I expected. I thought it goes through all user controls on form. But I was wrong. When user control received focus (using mouse click) it didn't want to go anyway using tab button. What thing can be wrong ? Did I miss something ?

I didn't override ProcessCmdKey and other key_down events. All user controls have TabStop property = true.

C#, .net 2.0, WinForms

Comment: Have you set numbers to TabIndex Property?

Comment: @AEMLoviji, yes, I set numbers to TabIndex property.

Comment: @AEMLoviji, Some controls have nested user controls.

Comment: It could be validation. If the user control you focused is invalid state, it does not allow you to move focus out of it.

Comment: @Dmitry, no, my user controls don't have any validation...

Answer (score 0):

you can use "Tab Order" tool in "Layout" toolbar to see the current TabIndex values. make sure TabIndex is correct (starts from 0) including tabIndex in the actual UserControl as well. quickly tried on mine and seems to work. Do u have any binding setup to these controls